# How to get images and container to have the same height

Tags: html, css

I am having troubles getting two `inline-block` sections (`#sec2BlockA` and `#sec2BlockB`) to line up with height. I want the two sections to always be the same height. Right now the image is too short and for some reason the `object-fit:cover` is not expanding the image to cover the entire area.

Then the `.bottomArrowButton` is overlapping the right side text.

Dependent on the viewport and text quantity, I am wanting all section to pair up, like the two images below:

[image]

[image]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong with this formation. Does anyone see what I could do.

```css
#sec2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#sec2BlockA,
#sec2BlockB {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#sec2BlockA {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#sec2BlockA img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#sec2BlockB {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#sec2BlockBWrap {
  height: auto;
}

.bottomArrowButton {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  background: #EDEDED;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .35s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
}

.bottomArrowButton:hover {
  transition: all .35s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
  background: #000;
}

.bottomArrowButton:hover .moreEventsLink {
  color: #FFF;
}

.bottomArrowButton:hover .rightArrow {
  background-size: 15px 15px;
  background-repeat: none;
  transition: all .35s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
  transform: translateX(15px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(15px);
}

.moreEventsLink {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #58595b;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<section id="sec2">
  <div id="sec2BlockA">
    <img src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mbkitsystems/engineer.jpg" alt="Testing">
  </div>
  <div id="sec2BlockB">
    <div class="sec80" id="Sec2BlockBWrap">
      <h2 class="blockTG">Testing</h2>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <p class="dG">
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
      </p>
      <p class="dG">
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
      </p>
    </div>
    <a href="solutions.php">
      <div class="bottomArrowButton">
        <div class="total-center">
          <span class="moreEventsLink">BUTTON</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you post a pen or fiddle for this?

Comment: jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g414jjbz/

Comment: Do both the `sec2Block`s have to be displayed as `inline-block`? because you can achieve this with absolutely positioning one of them?

Answer (score 2):

The problem overlapping is because of position absolute of the `bottomArrowButton`, being absolute positioned it removes it from the flow.

```
.bottomArrowButton {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    background: #EDEDED;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .35s ease;-webkit-transition:all .35s ease;
}
```

For a solution I would be using flex:

```
#sec2 {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: That's not true

Comment: bottomArrowButton is overlapping Sec2BlockBWrap because of the position absolute.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

The problem is that in CSS `height: 100%` works if it's parent has height set.

In your case you have `height: auto` which is why, the right element has lower height.

If you change height from `auto` to for example `500px` it works properly.

**Solution 2**

You can also change relative elemnt like here:

```css
#sec2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#sec2BlockA,
#sec2BlockB {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#sec2BlockA {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#sec2BlockA img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#sec2BlockB {
  width: 59%;
  height: 100%;
}

#sec2BlockBWrap {
  height: auto;
}

.bottomArrowButton {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  background: #EDEDED;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .35s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
}

.bottomArrowButton:hover {
  transition: all .35s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
  background: #000;
}

.bottomArrowButton:hover .moreEventsLink {
  color: #FFF;
}

.bottomArrowButton:hover .rightArrow {
  background-size: 15px 15px;
  background-repeat: none;
  transition: all .35s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
  transform: translateX(15px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(15px);
}

.moreEventsLink {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #58595b;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<section id="sec2">
  <div id="sec2BlockA">
    <img src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mbkitsystems/engineer.jpg" alt="Testing">
  </div>
  <div id="sec2BlockB">
    <div class="sec80" id="Sec2BlockBWrap">
      <h2 class="blockTG">Testing</h2>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <p class="dG">
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
      </p>
      <p class="dG">
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
      </p>
    </div>
    <a href="solutions.php">
      <div class="bottomArrowButton">
        <div class="total-center">
          <span class="moreEventsLink">BUTTON</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The issue is this section needs to have adaptive height

Comment: Thank you, but another part of it is that my image is not covering the whole `#sec2` container.  Any ideas on that part of it?

Comment: @Paul What exactly do you mean? Do you want the picture to be a background?

Comment: Watch out, if the image height will be smaller than the right text, the bottomArrowButton will overlap the text, as I was saying that bottomArrowButton overlaps the text because of position absolute.

Comment: I am wanting the image to cover that whole container. That is why I used `object-fit:cover`, but it doesn't seem to be working once the image gets larger in size.

Answer (score 2):

object fit only works if both dimensions are defined.  If your right content is always going to be taller, you can absolutely position your left div so the `height:100%` will work on the image:

```css
#sec2 {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#sec2BlockA,
#sec2BlockB {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#sec2BlockA {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 40%;
}

#sec2BlockA img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#sec2BlockB {
  width: 60%;
  position: relative;
  left:40%;
}

#sec2BlockBWrap {
  height: auto;
}

.bottomArrowButton {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  background: #EDEDED;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .35s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
}

.bottomArrowButton:hover {
  transition: all .35s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
  background: #000;
}

.bottomArrowButton:hover .moreEventsLink {
  color: #FFF;
}

.bottomArrowButton:hover .rightArrow {
  background-size: 15px 15px;
  background-repeat: none;
  transition: all .35s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
  transform: translateX(15px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(15px);
}

.moreEventsLink {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #58595b;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<section id="sec2">
  <div id="sec2BlockA">
    <img src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mbkitsystems/engineer.jpg" alt="Testing">
  </div>
  <div id="sec2BlockB">
    <div class="sec80" id="Sec2BlockBWrap">
      <h2 class="blockTG">Testing</h2>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <p class="dG">
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
      </p>
      <p class="dG">
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
      </p>
    </div>
    <a href="solutions.php">
      <div class="bottomArrowButton">
        <div class="total-center">
          <span class="moreEventsLink">BUTTON</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```